# Render/ submit jsf form with conditionally chosen different input component types but submitting to same bean field

Tags: jsf

Is it ok, in JSF, to render & submit a form with conditionally chosen different input components but all submitting to the same bean field like as shown below:
 (At any given time, only 1 type of input component is chosen)

```
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="..cond1..">
                    <p:inputText value="#{lobCr.text}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="..cond2..">
                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{lobCr.text}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="..cond3..">
                    <h:inputHidden value="#{lobCr.text}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="..." />
            </h:form>
```

I've tested this out & although this works fine as expected, I just fear of any unknown issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine , your form will only submit the values for rendered component